# Scala monads - "value map is not a member of" error

Tags: scala, monads, scala-cats

I have created a simple `trait` and service:

```
@finalAlg
@autoFunctorK(true)
trait BettingService[F[_]] {    
  def put(bet: Bet): F[Bet]
}

class BettingServiceMock[F[_] : Async] extends BettingService[F] {
  override def put(bet: Bet): F[Bet] = {
    val id = randomUUID().toString
    for {
      created <- Bet(BetId(id), bet.stake, bet.name)
    } yield created
  }
}
```

`Bet` and `BetId` are `case classes`:

```
case class Bet(betId: BetId, stake: BigDecimal, name: String)

case class BetId(betId: String) extends AnyVal
```

When I ran this program, I got an error: `Error:(12, 21) value map is not a member of model.Bet <- Bet(BetId(id), bet.stake, bet.name)` It is something strange for me - why I cannot return good type from `for-comprehension`? The idea of this is to return same object as given as parameter, but with random id.

I thought that maybe I need instance of new `Bet` class, but then I could not return it as `F[_]` as I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Bet(BetId(id), bet.stake, bet.name)` is of type `Bet` but expected type is `F[Bet]`.

Try

```
import cats.syntax.functor._

for {
  created <- Applicative[F].pure(Bet(BetId(id), bet.stake, bet.name))
} yield created
```

or

```
import cats.syntax.functor._
import cats.syntax.applicative._

for {
  created <- Bet(BetId(id), bet.stake, bet.name).pure
} yield created
```

or

```
Applicative[F].pure(Bet(BetId(id), bet.stake, bet.name))
```

or

```
import cats.syntax.applicative._

Bet(BetId(id), bet.stake, bet.name).pure
```

Comment: but `created` is a type F[Bet] because I do not have an error here. Explicity of calling `pure` is a good practise?

Comment: `created` is not of type `F[Bet]`.

Comment: If `fa` is of type `F[A]` then `a` in `a <- fa` is of type `A`.

Comment: @allocer This is not question of good practice, this is question of compilation.