# Scala cats - problem with encoding/decoding jsons

Tags: json, scala, scala-cats, circe, http4s

I have created a simple routes:

```
class MyRoutes[F[_] : Async](service: MyService[F]) extends Http4sDsl[F] {

  def routes: HttpRoutes[F] = HttpRoutes.of[F] {
    case req@PUT -> Root / "bets" =>
      for {
        bet <- req.as[Bet]
        created <- service.put(bet)
        response <- Created(created)
      } yield response
}
```

and a jsons `implicits` for input and output:

```
object jsons {
  implicit def circeDecoder[A[_] : Sync, B: Decoder]: EntityDecoder[A, B] = jsonOf[A, B]
  implicit def circeEncoder[A[_] : Sync, B: Encoder]: EntityEncoder[A, B] = jsonEncoderOf[A, B]
}
```

But when I ran this program via Postman, I got an error:
`The request body was invalid.` with `422` error code. I think it is something wrong with json encoder and decoder, because my request was very simple and clear:

```
{       
    "stake": 434,
    "name": "Something"
}
```

I tried to add an implicit decoder into routes:

```
 implicit val betDecoder: EntityDecoder[F, Bet] = jsonOf[F, Bet]
```

but it also did not help. Could anyone help me with that and tell how to create good encoder and decoder for jsons? I use `circe` library for parsing.

Comment: Where's the definition of `Bet` and a `Decoder` for `Bet`?

Comment: @Koterpillar TS defined `Bet` in his previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55767864/scala-monads-value-map-is-not-a-member-of-error). I guess decoder for `Bet` is auto-generated by Circe. I guess the code is
https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/bbf886b02007f09964b512cfd15208b9

Comment: @DmytroMitin yes, it looks like similar to this. So if encoder and decoder are auto-generated by Circe so why it does not work correctly?

Comment: If you're deriving a decoder for a case class, it will expect all members of the case class to be in the JSON. Please provide your complete definitions—it's impossible to guess what's wrong with the question as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, stupid me, I solved the problem. 
I had (probably) wrong definition of `Bet`. It was:

```
case class Bet(betId: BetId, stake: BigDecimal, name: String)

case class BetId(betId: String) extends AnyVal
```

So I should to give `Id` as a parameter. I changed the code to this one:

```
case class Bet(betId: Option[BetId], stake: BigDecimal, name: String)

case class BetId(betId: String) extends AnyVal
```

and after this one everything works correctly. 
Another question is - is it good practise or could it be done in better way?

Comment: For me it's ok. Even better option would be to create two case classes, like `PartialBet` (without id) and `Bet` with `Id`. Then when you assign id to your entity just map it to wider case class. You can do it manually or maybe use library like [henkan](https://github.com/kailuowang/henkan). Yet another option is to assign id on client side as uuid.

Comment: Thanks. Do not know this lib, but looks like interesting.